# Get Image from camera into ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-camera, galaxy-nexus

The following code works well to get the thumbnail of a picture taken from the camera. I want to get the full image, not just the thumbnail. I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1111;

private ImageView mImage;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_camera);
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            mImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a full size picture you need to first save it to file and then extract it's bitmap from it, do this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
 startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_NEW_PICTURE);
```

Then in `onActivityResult`:

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
 mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 mImage.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 250));
```

When `decodeSampledBitmapFromFile`:

```
    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        }

        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }


    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
  }
```

You can play with the numbers (500 and 250 in this case) to change the quality of the bitmap for the `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks very much, but I'm saving the image somewhere that is not obvious, would it be an easy way to save it into the Image Gallery?

Comment: Image Gallery is just another folder in your phone that contains your pics. I don't think it will matter. what do you mean by "not obvious"?

Comment: By not obvious I mean it's not easy for the average user to find the picture, since it's not stored in the Image Gallery folder